# jQuery Mobile window.resize() on data-role="page" load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Lazy Load with jQuery Mobile and it requires a 1px scroll to trigger the first image load. `$(window).resize();` works just fine but it's only firing on the site load.

jQuery mobile uses div's that contain `data-role="page"` instead of separate pages. So the mobile site is essentially one page.

How would I trigger `$(window).resize();` every time a new `data-role="page"` is loaded?

Comment: `$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role=page]', function () { $(window).resize(); });` have you tried this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind your code to `pageshow` event.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role=page]', function () { 
 $(window).resize();
});
```